# Customise Salesforce Login Screen

Tags: login, theme-branding

Is it possible to customise the Salesforce Login screen if an Org is using the `My Domain` feature?

**Login Screen**

[image]

For example:

- Custom Logo
- Custom Colours
- Custom Image on the right side

Comment: check this video. http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/oFQ26FCXPVOA90xZaVDDjA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, check this out trailhead module for more info

[Customize Your Login Process with My Domain](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/identity_login/units/identity_login_my_domain)

Also watch this video for similar info [SETTING UP A MY DOMAIN](http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/oFQ26FCXPVOA90xZaVDDjA)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We can customize the Salesforce Login page if the org is using **My Domain** Feature.

We can use the custom logo and custom color as well. But for the right side, we can only provide the URL.

Refer below link for more info
[Customize Salesforce Login Page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_login_branding.htm&type=5)